# Authentication via TCP Header in Concrete5

Tags: tcp, concrete5

We are trying to build a secure authentication process for administrator login to concrete5.  Two questions:

1. Can we use a different IP for the back end -- at least the login process?
2. Can Concrete5 8.1.0 accept a TCP header injection of:
   `SSLClientCertSubject C=XXXX, O=XXXX, OU=XXXX, OU=XXXX, OU=XXXX, CN=Info1.Info2.1234567890`
   If so, I would then like to parse out the last 10 characters and use it as an Administrator signin or at least be able to validate it matches a known Administrator.

Comment: Are we possibly taking about HTTP headers as opposed to TCP segment headers?

Answer (score 0):

concrete5 *does* offer the ability to build custom **authentication types** and that process is [one of the better documented parts of the core](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/users-groups/advanced-creating-custom-authentication-type).

---

#### To answer your questions specifically:

> Can we use a different IP for the back end -- at least the login process?

This is something you'd do at your server level; force all traffic to /login to happen on the host that you'd like.

> Can Concrete5 8.1.0 accept a TCP header injection

Under typical circumstances, PHP doesn't have the opportunity to interact with raw TCP traffic. However, [it is possible - with sockets - to listen on a port and inspect traffic](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php).

---

What you're asking is possible, but it's going to be fairly challenging to build it the way you are hoping to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a Two-step authentication process instead. It's fairly secure and there's a plugin ready on the marketplace (full disclosure, I built it)